# Error Instance Method -initwithFrame:imageName:imgname not found Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I am now getting only 1 error in GalleryScrollView.m. I think I'm declaring the Gallery button wrong.

The error is:

```
Instance Method -initwithFrame:imageName:imgname not found
```

With this line:

```
 GalleryButton *btnAttachment = [[GalleryButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height) imageName:imgName];
```

I have tried `- (void) removeAttachment:(GalleryButton *)button imageName;`

but that does not seem to work. Below is my code.

Any comments or answers is of great appreciation.

Thanks.

**GalleryScrollView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AttachmentItem.h"
#import "GalleryButton.h"

@protocol GAlleryScrollDelegate;

@interface GalleryScrollView : UIView <GalleryButtonDelegate>

{

id <GAlleryScrollDelegate> delegate;

// MAIN WINDOW WHERE YOU CAN DRAG ICONS
UIView *mainView;

UIScrollView *_scrollView;
NSMutableArray *_attachments;


NSInteger *_totalSize;

UIImageView *_recycleBin;
CGRect recycleBinFrame;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <GAlleryScrollDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *mainView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *attachments;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *recycleBin;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect recycleBinFrame;

- (void) addAttachment:(AttachmentItem *)attachment withImageNamed:(NSString *)imgName;
- (void) removeAttachment:(GalleryButton *)button;
- (void) reloadData;

@end

// EVENTS IF YOU WANT TO DISABLE SOME SCROLL ON DID PRESS AND ENABLE IT ON DROP
@protocol GAlleryScrollDelegate
- (void) didPressButton;
- (void) didDropButton;
@end
```

**GalleryScrollView.m**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "GalleryScrollView.h"
#import "GalleryButton.h"

@implementation GalleryScrollView


@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize mainView;
@synthesize attachments = _attachments;
@synthesize recycleBin = _recycleBin, recycleBinFrame;


int padding = 0;


#pragma mark - INIT

- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
}
return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self){
    ;
}
return self;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
// INIT ATTACHMENT ARRAY
if (_attachments == nil){
    _attachments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

// SCROLL VIEW
UIScrollView *scrollTemp = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width-0, 450)];
_scrollView = scrollTemp;
_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// RECYCLE BIN
UIImageView *imageViewTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge.png"]];
self.recycleBin = imageViewTemp;
self.recycleBin.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 270);

[self addSubview:_scrollView];
[self addSubview:self.recycleBin];
[scrollTemp release];
[imageViewTemp release];
}

- (void) dealloc {
[super dealloc];

}

#pragma mark - ATTACHMENTS ADD / REMOVE

- (void) addAttachment:(AttachmentItem *)attachment withImageNamed:(NSString *)imgName
{
// SAVE ATTACHMENT
[_attachments addObject:attachment];

// RESIZE CONTENT VIEW FOR INSERTINT NEW ATTACHMENT
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([_attachments count]*70, 70);

CGFloat startX = (70.0f * ((float)[_attachments count] - 1.0f) + padding);
CGFloat startY = 370;
CGFloat width = 64;
CGFloat height = 64;

GalleryButton *btnAttachment = [[GalleryButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height) imageName:imgName];
btnAttachment.tag = [_attachments count];
btnAttachment.scrollParent = _scrollView;
btnAttachment.mainView = self.mainView;
btnAttachment.delegate = self;

if (attachment.type == 1){
}else if (attachment.type == 2){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
} else if (attachment.type == 3){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"recyclebin.png"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}

[_scrollView addSubview:btnAttachment];
[btnAttachment release];

}


- (void) removeAttachment:(GalleryButton *)button
{

}

#pragma mark - RELOAD DATA

- (void) reloadData
{

}

#pragma mark - GALLERY BUTTON DELEGATE

-(void) touchDown
{
[self.delegate didPressButton];
}

-(void) touchUp
{
[self.delegate didDropButton];
_scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

-(BOOL) isInsideRecycleBin:(GalleryButton *)button touching:(BOOL)finished;
{
CGPoint newLoc = [self convertPoint:self.recycleBin.frame.origin toView:self.mainView];
CGRect binFrame = self.recycleBin.frame;
binFrame.origin = newLoc;

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(binFrame, button.frame) == TRUE){
    if (finished){
        [self removeAttachment:button];
    }
    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}

}

@end
```

**GalleryButton.m**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "GalleryButton.h"
#import "GalleryScrollView.h"

@implementation GalleryButton

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize originalPosition = _originalPosition;
@synthesize mainView, scrollParent;
@synthesize images;

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
}

return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imgName
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    isInScrollview  = YES;

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64);
    images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];

    // here's the change:
    // instead of a constant name, use the `imgName` parameter
    [images setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];
    [self addSubview:images];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
}
return self;
}
#pragma mark - DRAG AND DROP

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[self.delegate touchDown];
self.originalPosition = self.center;
self.scrollParent.scrollEnabled = NO;

if (isInScrollview == YES) {
    CGPoint newLoc = CGPointZero;
    newLoc = [[self superview] convertPoint:self.center toView:self.mainView];
    _originalOutsidePosition = newLoc;

    //      [self.superview touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    [self removeFromSuperview];

    self.center = newLoc;
    [self.mainView addSubview:self];
    [self.mainView bringSubviewToFront:self];
    isInScrollview = NO;
}
else {
    ;
}

}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"stalk" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.001];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
self.center = [touch locationInView: self.superview];

[UIView commitAnimations];

if ([delegate isInsideRecycleBin:self touching:NO]){

}

}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if ([delegate isInsideRecycleBin:self touching:YES]){

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
    images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [images setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light-cherry.png"]];
    [self.mainView addSubview:images];

    UIImageView * animation = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    animation.frame = CGRectMake(self.center.x - 32, self.center.y - 32, 40, 40);

    animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem3.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem4.png"]
                                 ,nil];
    [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [animation setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    [animation startAnimating];
    [self.mainView addSubview:animation];
    [animation bringSubviewToFront:self.mainView];
    [animation release];
    ;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

} else{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}

[self.delegate touchUp];

}

-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"goback"] && finished) {
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    self.center = _originalPosition;
    [self.scrollParent addSubview:self];
    isInScrollview = YES;
}
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only problem you are facing here is that you didn't declare your `- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName` method. Make sure you have declare this method in your header file: `GalleryButton.h` with the same [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature).

Comment: Now it gives me a warning GalleryButton may not respond to iniWithFrame:imageNamed ? Any reason why after i declared in my header file - (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName;

Comment: did u declare ur ivar as a GalleryButton or a UIButton? if it is a GalleryButton u shouldn't have this warning. You shouln't ignore at all this warning since ur method might not be called

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `initWithFrame` method to

```
 - (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName
    {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self){
        ;
    }
    return self;
    }
```

don't forget to declare this method in .h file as well

Answer (score 0):

just check whether GalleryButton.m contain initWithFrame method or not.  Also, check whether you have declared the method signature in your GalleryButton.h class.

Answer (score 0):

It would be rather useful to check the `GalleryButton` class, since the problem is with this:

```
 GalleryButton *btnAttachment = [[GalleryButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height) imageName:imgName];
```

But it seems that you didn't implemented that method on that class.